# Why does burning things make them black?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, visible-light

It's not clear to me how burning process can transform a material which was previously capable both of absorbing and emitting photon to one which can only absorb them. I would like to hear an educated explanation for how the burning process alters that property of matter: what is happening to the energy levels that the material used to have before it was burned?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Burning doesn't transform everything into a black color.  It just so happens that the final products for some of the most common materials tend to be black:

- When organic matter is burned, the remaining material tends to be black due the presence of graphitic carbon that remains as a result of dehydration.  (Sulfuric acid has the same effect on organic matter.)
- The carbon presence in flames (due to the material used as fuel) can also leave materials covered in a thin layer of black color.  This occurs when you burn wood or candles.
- Some of the oxides (copper for example) are black, or very dark.

Many oxides are not black: e.g. iron oxide (rust) is not black.  Many transition metals have very colorful oxides.

Comment: I will try to rephrase my question - why the most common final products of burning process are black? What is generally happening to the energy levels of a molecule that was heated?

Comment: It's mainly because of carbon, so a better question would be to ask why elemental carbon (graphite) happens to be black.  Heat (a physical process) itself doesn't affect the energy levels significantly; the cause lies in the oxidation (which is a chemical process) of the material.

Comment: @fzlogic And elemental carbon can be a hard, transparent crystal: diamond.

Comment: @Kaz, yes. if you could provide the temperature and pressure needed to organize its atoms into the crystalline structure. Highly doubt that you can do it by burning.